# NO JSP Support for /, did not find

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using sonar 3.4.1, I've done jdbc configuration on sonar.properties, but when I want to start the server, I'm having this error :

```
    | 2013-10-07 15:30:24.061:INFO::Logging to org.sonar.application.FilteredLogger@4ee1d5ea via org.sonar.application.FilteredLogger
    | 2013-10-07 15:30:24.146:INFO::jetty-6.1.25
    | 2013-10-07 15:30:24.448:INFO::NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
    | JRuby limited openssl loaded. http://jruby.org/openssl
    | gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
    | 2013-10-07 15:30:45.912:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9000
```

In the sonar log i have this exception :

```
2013.10.07 14:21:23 ERROR o.s.c.p.Database  Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.').
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429) ~[commons-dbcp-1.3.jar:1.3]
    at
```

Comment: Did you add the Oracle JDBC driver into SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle ? See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Requirements for supported drivers.